# Publishing Ionic App from Batch

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I want to create a batch file to execute `jarsigner` and `zipalign` commands to publish my app. I wrote this because I want to put `app-release-unsigned.apk` in the same folder of my `.bat` file, the folder is Publish Tools on my Desktop.

```
cd C:\Users\tgiak\Desktop\Publish Tools

start /w /b "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore taba.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk tabaapp"

start /w /b "C:\Users\tgiak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk"
```

It doesn't give me any error, but it does nothing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to try the following:

```
Start "" /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\jarsigner" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore taba.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk tabaapp

Start "" "%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign" -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
```

I have replaced, `C:\Program Files` with `%ProgramFiles%` and `C:\Users\tgiak\AppData\Local` with `%LocalAppData%` . Those were not part of the fix, *just an optional improvement*.

If you're, using a command and having problems, it's always a good idea to read the command usage help in the command prompt window, i.e. `Start /?`

Comment: I got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### It says that it can't find the file

> ```
> start "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin" "jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore taba.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk tabaapp"
> ```

The above command makes no sense. The above uses `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin` as the title for the `cmd` window.

If you are trying to run `jarsigner` then the following makes more sense:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore taba.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk tabaapp"
```

Where I have replaced `" "` with `\`

You can also check that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin` is in your path (see [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)).

If it is you can use any title you like ...

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: How I can wait the first command to finish before execute the second? Do the files i need to sign to be in the jarsigner folder or to be in my .bat folder?

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli `start /wait`. See the further reading links. Probably you need to `cd /d locationofthefiles` at the start of the batch file.